# How to set a text view at the left edge of another textview? 

Tags: android

I have to draw two textviews such that when one text view ends, the other textview begins at the pervious ones left edge.  I have to do this programatically as the text in each may vary.
How do I get the  x co-ordinate of the left edge of the first textview and how do I set the right edge of the second textview to match the left edge of the first one.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
here is my layout

```
<TextView android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="10dip" android:id="@+id/updateorder"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="x" style="@style/compactview" android:background="@drawable/ornage"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginRight="73dip"></TextView>
<TextView style="@style/compactview" android:id="@+id/neworder"
    android:textColor="#000000" android:background="@drawable/red1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/updateorder" android:text="x"
    android:textSize="10dip" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/updateorder"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to do this programaticaly ..
Just Define The two layout as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView1"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView2"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    ></TextView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can achieve this thing using code as well
But clearly no need to get any exact position for a view.

Comment: i have given my layout above, but somehow the second textbox is not aligning besides the first one.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentRight="true" this making the first view in the right of screen and android:layout_toRightOf="@id/updateorder" the second view to right of it which is going out of view ...

set the first view not to align parent right

Comment: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" try this for first view and then change according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Look on [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) documentation and `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_toRightOf` attributes. You can find sample usage in this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117112714/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/relativelayout-in-android-xml.html). What's more, if you set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` you don't have to do anything programmatically.

Comment: i have to set the parameters dynamically.